# Short exact sequence makes exact triangle in derived category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

I am reading through the appendix of *Commutative Algebra - with a View Towards Algebraic Geometry* and I came across essentially the following question: 
Suppose that 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>> F' @>\alpha>> F @>\beta>> F'' @>>> 0
\end{CD}
is a short exact sequence of complexes from a category $\mathcal{A}$, show that it induces an exact triangle in $D(\mathcal{A})$, but not necessarily in $K(\mathcal{A})$.

As a hint, it says to prove that $F''$  is quasi-isomorphic to $M(\alpha)$ (the mapping cone of $\alpha$) by showing that 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>>M(\alpha') @>>> M(\alpha) @>>> F'' @>>> 0
\end{CD}
is a short exact sequence of complexes, where $\alpha'$ is the isomorphism from $F'$ to $\alpha(F')\subset F$.

I can show that the latter is indeed a short exact sequence, but that's it. I am quite new to derived categories and the concept of exact triangles in general is quite confusing to me.

Comment: I think you need to read some materials about triangulated category and derived category, then you can understand this question. Actually $K(A)$ is a triangulated category, its distinguished triangles are the class of triangules that are isomorphic to the triangles induced by mapping cone. Derived category $D(A)$ is the verdier quotient of $K(A)$, it takes all quasi-isomorphisms in $K(A)$ to isomorphisms in $D(A)$.  We can get that for any short exact sequence of complexes of $A$, it induces a distinguished triangle in $D(A)$.

Comment: I will do that, thank you. I have two follow-up questions: 1) Is there a source where they explain derived categories with more (non-trivial) examples, I feel like that might help me. 2) Specifically to my question, I figured out how to do it, so should I answer my own question here (answer is quite long, but ultimately not hard) or is there a way to indicate that it doesn't need answering any more?

Comment: 1) maybe you can look at this book "triangulated categories in the representation theory of finite dimensional algebras" by Happle; 2) Of course you can answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\bbZ{\mathbb{Z}}
\def\sA{\mathcal{A}}
\def\hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$Other answers have already pointed out how to make a distinguished triangle in $D(\sA)$ out of any s.e.s. in $\sA$, and have explained why the s.e.s. of abelian groups $0\to \bbZ/2\bbZ\to\bbZ/4\bbZ\to\bbZ/2\bbZ\to 0$ does not give a distinguished triangle in $K(\mathsf{Ab})$. Here we will show:

> **Lemma.** Let $\sA$ be an additive category. A s.e.s. in $\mathcal{A}$ gives a distinguished triangle in $K(\mathcal{A})$ if and only if it is a split s.e.s. Moreover, if $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is a split short exact sequence, then the associated distinguished triangle in $K(\sA)$ is of the form $A[0]\to B[0]\to C[0]\xrightarrow{0}A[1]$.

*Proof.* Along the proof, we will use that $K(\sA)$ is a pre-triangulated category (see e.g. [014S](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014S)). The last claim is simply because $\hom_{K(\sA)}(C[0],A[1])=0$.

($\Leftarrow$). Use either [05QT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QT) or [014L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014L) (where $\delta$ is the map explained in [014I](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014I)).

($\Rightarrow$). We will give a detailed proof of the sketch in the second paragraph of [014Z](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014Z). Suppose $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is a s.e.s. in $\sA$ that gives a distinguished triangle in $K(\sA)$. The induced distinguished triangle is of the form $A[0]\to B[0]\to C[0]\xrightarrow{0}A[1]$. Since $K(\sA)$ is pre-triangulated, we deduce the existence of a map $f: B\to A\oplus C$ such that we have a morphism of distinguished triangles:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A[0] @>>> B[0] @>>> C[0] @>{0}>> A[1] \\
 @|             @V{f[0]}VV             @|           @|  \\
A[0] @>>>  A[0]\oplus C[0] @>>> C[0] @>{0}>> A[1]
\end{CD}
$$
Indeed, the bottom triangle is distinguished by either [05QT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05QT) or [014L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014L). Hence, by [014A](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014A), $f[0]$ is a homotopy equivalence. Since the functor $[0]:\mathcal{A}\to K(\mathcal{A})$ is fully faithful, we get that $f$ is an isomorphism and that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0@>>> A@>>>B@>>> C@>>> 0\\
@.@|@V{f}VV@|@.\\
0@>>> A@>>>A\oplus C@>>> C@>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
commutes in $\mathcal{A}$. Thus, the s.e.s. $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is split. $\square$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've forgot to answer my own question 5 years ago and its been so long that I can't remember how I solved it.